# Android Emulator - Cannot use Hardware GPU on Fedora 20 x64

Tags: android, linux, fedora

I recently installed Android SDK on my Fedora 20 64-bit installation and am trying to run the emulator using hardware acceleration but it seems to keep crashing right after Android boots up i.e. either at the lock screen or of I manage to unlock, it would soon get unresponsive for a few seconds before the emulator disappears off the screen.

I've been reading into a lot of posts and tried installing `mesa*.i686` since I had been getting a lot of errors in logcat from `EGL_Emulation` saying `Failed to connect to host (qemupipestream)` and `EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED` but this did not solve the problem.

Any thoughts on why I'm still unable to use my hardware GPU? Any areas that I might be overlooking would be a great help.

There are no error messages in logcat when the emulator goes unresponsive besides the ones above that have already occurred almost 10 seconds before the emulator hangs up and then disappears. Also, might be worth noting that in the cases where I unlock and browse around the apps, it does seem that it has HW GPU enabled.

Any thoughts?

**Additional details:**
Turns out that if I restart adb server, the emulator seems to run for a bit longer (maybe about 30 to 40 seconds more from the point it would crash). In case that helps in trying to figure out what might be going on.

Comment: Are there any messages in system logs after crashing?

Comment: Nope. I checked there already but nothing in the system logs.

Comment: I had problems (I don't remember their roots) which were solved by adding -use-system-libs to emulator run command, as example: android_sdk/emulator/emulator -gpu host -avd tablet_nexus_api_27 -use-system-libs

Comment: Additionally, I'm using optirun to run emulator (as my laptop has hybrid videocard). Without opritun it's failing pretty fast and often.